# Defining a REST api

Tags: web-services, rest, api-design

I was wondering what the most correct or best practice way to define a rest api would be.  Lets say I have an application that deals with cars and their parts/components.  Any api will always start first with the top level car.  So, in defining my api should I go with:

```
[url]/{resourceName}/{carId}/{resouorceId}
```

so as an example, lets say I want to get an engine, so:

```
[url]/engine/123/456
```

where 123 is the car id and 456 is the engine id.  Or, is it a better practice to place the resource after the top level container, in this case a car, so something like:

```
[url]/{carId}/{resourceName}/{resourceId}
```

so the same example would be:

```
[url]/123/engine/456
```

Or does it matter?  Is there an "industry best practice" type of approach?  As I understand it, most of what I read has said something to the effect of "make the api intuitive and easy to understand".

Also, does or should the api be fully expressive, for example, should all api's regardless of approach be something like below even though the api is always for a car for this particular application.

```
[url]/car/{carId}/{resourceName}/{resourceId}
```

so, examples being:

```
[url]/car/123/engine/456
[url]/car/123/wheel/1
```

I understand this could be interpreted as a post that will just create debate, but I am really looking for help in tracking down what might be most widely accepted.

Comment: My understanding is that there is no real "industry best practice".  Different people take different approaches to whether to use singular or plural, what to put in URL parameters vs payload.  You will get different opinions based on who you ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REST really has nothing to do with URIs or HTTP. It is not a standard; it's an architectural *style* or *paradigm*. In Roy Fielding's thesis, he identifies certain criteria for an architectural style to be "RESTful". It just so happens that HTTP satisfies these criteria, which makes it a good *protocol* to realize a RESTful architecture. But REST itself has *nothing* to do with HTTP.

In REST URI's are opaque, meaning they don't convey any other semantic other than uniquely identifying a resource. So for example, a URI like `/dfjSuX7kx` is perfectly valid. Of course, that doesn't mean we have to use URI's like that; it's better to use something you can make sense of.

You wanted to know whether you should go with:

```
[url]/{resourceName}/{carId}/{resourceId}
```

I would say that it is better to go with just:

```
[url]/{resourceName}/{resourceId}
```

And then make `carId` part of the representation. Why is that? We know that one of the requirements is that your URI must *uniquely* identify a resource. Right now we have an engine `456` that is part of car `123`, which means that you are identifying that particular resource with the URI `/engine/123/456`. But let's say car `123` was totaled and the engine was moved to car `789`. Now your URI for the *same* resource is `/engine/789/456`. Keep in mind here that *nothing* about engine `456` has changed; it is still the *same* engine. The only thing is that it is now attached to a different car. But that doesn't mean that the URI that uniquely identifies it has to change as well (because then it would no-longer *uniquely* identify it). What identifies an engine *uniquely* is its id, and *not* the car that it is attached to. Hence it's better to just have `/engine/456` and return a representation like:

```
{
    "id": 456,
    "carId": 123,
    "cylinders": 6,
    "hp": 350,
    ...
}
```

You also asked if you could do this:

```
[url]/{carId}/{resourceName}/{resourceId}
```

I would not recommend that at all. Let's say you have hosted your API at `http://my.car-api.com`. What does `http://my.car-api.com/123` actually mean? Of course, it's RESTful because URI's are opaque, but it's hard to understand what it means when looking at the URI, so it's better to use `/car/{carId}`.

For your final question, you asked if the following is acceptable:

```
[url]/car/{carId}/{resourceName}/{resourceId}
```

Subresources are ok, and I have seen people use it, and I have also used it in some REST API's I have created. But personally I'm moving towards giving every resource a top-level URI. This is because we can already convey hierarchical relationships or the concept of "ownership" via the representation we return from the URI, instead of encoding that into the URI itself (remember, the URI has no additional meaning other than the fact that it uniquely identifies a resource). I've also noticed issues with orthogonality in the way I implement my controllers, error-handlers and transformers (helper classes that convert DTO's to domain objects and vice-versa); supporting a nested URI-structure makes it hard for me to write general code (although some of this is due to the way the framework I'm using, Spring, does things).

You can decide how "RESTful" you want to be; the best metric I've seen for quantifying the RESTfulness of your API is the [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html). I would suggest that you decide on a level that you're comfortable with. It's not necessary to be completely dogmatic and be completely RESTful; it depends on your situation. But I have found that getting to Level 3 (HATEOAS) has brought me a lot of benefits because my custom media-types (i.e. I use `application/vnd.my.api.resource.v1+json` instead of just `application/json`) are well-documented and convey their semantics very well. Also none of my clients have to construct URIs, since they can just follow links. The representations are self-documenting as well, since you can follow links to associated documentation, for instructions on processing resources.

The only thing I would *strongly* suggest is picking a style and sticking with it. I don't like to mix paradigms; so if you are aiming to have something RESTful, don't let anything RPC-ish sneak into your API. This can be a little difficult because REST is noun-based and RPC is verb-based (i.e. behavior), and some concepts just map quite easily over to RPC. An example is if you had a Bank API where you wanted to provide the ability to transfer money from one account to another. A "REST" implementation that is really RPC-ish may expose a URI like `/account/{accountId}/transfer?to={toAccountId}&amount={amount}` (which directly maps to a method call on an `Account` object: `account.transfer(amount, toAccountId)`; hence RPC). The RESTful way would be to expose a `transaction` resource at `/transaction`, where you would post something like:

```
{
    "from_account_id": 123,
    "to_account_id": 456,
    "amount": "100.00"
}
```

and the `/transaction` could respond with:

```
{
    "id": 789,
    "source_account_id": 123,
    "destination_account_id": 456,
    "amount": "100.00",
    "_links": {
        "self": { "href": "/transaction/789" }
    }
}
```

A lot of times people end up duplicating what HTTP already provides through RPC calls. For example, HTTP already gives you methods that translate to CRUD operations (quick note: the methods themselves have nothing to do with CRUD semantics; they just happen to map over conveniently), and also has response codes that convey information about the endresult of the operation (Was it successful? Did it fail? Why did it fail? etc.). The idea with REST is that you can concentrate on modeling your resources, their representations, and their relationships with each other and use what HTTP already provides you (hypermedia, response codes, methods) instead of duplicating all of that.

Comment: Vivin have looked at RAML yet? It is a very interesting way of documenting REST API's.

Comment: @Namphibian Yes I did and I tried it out for a while. Unfortunately it has some shortcomings; there is no way to document different responses based on query-parameter values for example. I've been using Apiary instead and it is pretty good - they are also adding the ability to document different responses based on query parameters.

Comment: sounds pretty good. The only problem I have had with REST so far is creating proper documentation for teams of developers to ensure the services are all in line with what I planned. RAML seemed to fill the gap there to some extent. WIll go look Apiary and give it a spin. The nice thing about SOAP services is that the documentation tools are pretty mature.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation tooling isn't quite there yet. But Apiary does a great job IMHO.

Comment: Just started with Apiary and it looks like REST tools are finally starting to catch up. These tools are a must for large enterprise corporations and one of the reasons REST has seen some resistance into banking SOA services which uses the extremely well documented IFX standard for example. With tools like this I think we should create a IFXREST variant. Lol. However this does allow for contract first type development which is the way I prefer it. Solve the problem in my head then commit to code. Excellent tip thanks.

Comment: Np. :) I hope REST doesn't get too much like SOAP! Some of the rationale for using REST is so that you don't have to deal with all of the idiosyncracies of SOAP. I think we've achieved that with mixed results in REST ;)

Comment: @Vivin Awesome answer!  That is exactly the type of answer I was looking for.  Very thorough and helpful!